# How to configure server to use single NIC

Tags: asp.net, nic

I am developing web server (C#).
How can I specify single network interface that can be used for communication with clients and restrict others?
I cannot simply disable them because I might use them for connection to the WCF service.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could bind an IP address to that NIC and then configure your server to only listen to requests on that IP address.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? IIS binds to 0.0.0.0:80 by default I guess, and I still need to have possibility to use other NICs.

Comment: This needs to go to ServerFault or similar -- what you're purposing is typically going to be administered by a non-programmer and there are standard ways to do these things based on the specific stack you're using. Now that we've established you're using IIS an admin should be able to help you. I'll flag the question to go there.